# Test two rates significance in R

Tags: r, testing, significance

Suppose I have an aggregated data like:

```
sex  sum_0            sum_1          change(%)
F   3.959894e+07    76818534.081    93.99140
M   4.993971e+07    83843894.295    67.89025
```

I wanted to test if there is significantly difference between Female and Male regarding the change(%).

Not sure if there is a R function can do this simple test given I don't have raw data to do the test.

Thanks!

Comment: Traditional significance tests require information about sample size and sample variance. Is this all the information you have?

Comment: You need to figure out a statistics model for your test first, then look for a solution in R. It isn't SAS when you do a few random clicks without knowing what your assumptions are.

Comment: As a starter, I suggest you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Common_test_statistics

Comment: Thanks ribo and zoff for your response. I just wanted to do a quick check about this data.  Modelling of course will be ideal but for a quick check I was hoping a R function ca do it.